# Paste JSON as Classes Duplicates and Numbers Elements as Unique Classes

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2019

I have the following section of JSON coming from Shopify:

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "total_line_items_price_set": {
                "shop_money": {
                    "amount": "281.96",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                },
                "presentment_money": {
                    "amount": "281.96",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                }
            },
            "total_discounts_set": {
                "shop_money": {
                    "amount": "0.00",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                },
                "presentment_money": {
                    "amount": "0.00",
                    "currency_code": "USD"
                }
            },
        },
```

When I utilize the Paste JSON as Classes feature I am getting elements like "shop_money" and "presentment_money" repeated and numbered as individual classes.

```cs
    public class Total_Line_Items_Price_Set
    {
        public Shop_Money shop_money { get; set; }
        public Presentment_Money presentment_money { get; set; }
    }

    public class Shop_Money
    {
        public string amount { get; set; }
        public string currency_code { get; set; }
    }

    public class Presentment_Money
    {
        public string amount { get; set; }
        public string currency_code { get; set; }
    }

    public class Total_Discounts_Set
    {
        public Shop_Money1 shop_money { get; set; }
        public Presentment_Money1 presentment_money { get; set; }
    }

    public class Shop_Money1
    {
        public string amount { get; set; }
        public string currency_code { get; set; }
    }

    public class Presentment_Money1
    {
        public string amount { get; set; }
        public string currency_code { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm new to JSON and how it should be represented as classes in C# - this seems wrong. Is it possible to get a better result?

SOLUTION:

Based on the answer by Zakk Diaz I removed each class that was duplicated and numbered. Having done so I am successfully deserializing and making use of an array of order objects.

```cs
    public class Orders
    {
        public Order[] orders { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        // [...]
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // [...]

            Orders testOrders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Orders>(responseFromServer);
            Console.WriteLine(testOrders.orders[0].id);
            Console.WriteLine(testOrders.orders[0].total_line_items_price_set.shop_money.amount);
            Console.WriteLine(testOrders.orders[0].line_items[1].price_set.shop_money.amount);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Paste it in [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/) (after you have fixed it, maybe using [Json Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)), and see what comes out of it. The Visual Studio standar converter is not really top of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine for the most part, you can delete these classes and rename them in "Total_Discounts_Set"

```
    public class Shop_Money1
{
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string currency_code { get; set; }
}

public class Presentment_Money1
{
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string currency_code { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it added Shop_Money1 and Shop_Money because whatever tool you're using can't tell that they should be the same class